# Python Theano tensor @as_op - use a dictionary as itypes?

Tags: python, theano

I'm doing Bayesian analysis using PyMC3 package and use Theano. If I wanted to use two parameters, I was able to do,

`@as_op(itypes=[theano.tensor.dscalar, theano.tensor.dscalar], otypes=[theano.tensor.dvector])`

Now my input is a dictionary containing the names and values. What should be my `itypes`. Please help.